# is select all selcetors effects on the DOM speed?

Tags: jquery

I am using this in my jquery code:

```
$("*").removeClass("out");
```

is this will slow down the DOM rendering ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$("*")` can be very slow when the DOM tree is very large.

In your case, it makes more sense to use `$(".out").removeClass("out");` since you don't really care about all nodes that have no `out` class.